# Hibernate getHibernateTemplate issue when saving object inside another object

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, foreign-keys

I recently changed my code to make reference to the getHibernateTemplate(), and now my forms don't seem to save correctly, here's the code:

```
  public void saveForm(EcoFormFill form, int userId)
  throws RemoteException
  {
    User tmpUser = (User)getHibernateTemplate().load(User.class, new Integer(userId));
    form.setUser(tmpUser);
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(form);
  }
```

It complains that it can't set the 'user_id' to be null (a constraint in my DB)... Previously I was using this approach:

```
  public void saveForm(EcoFormFill form, int userId)
  throws RemoteException
  {
    Session ses = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try
    {
      User tmpUser = (User) ses.load(User.class, new Integer(userId));
      form.setUser(tmpUser);
      ses.saveOrUpdate(form);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new RemoteException(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
      ses.flush();
      ses.close();
    }
  }
```

And this approach works just fine, but it gives me grief with unit tests, so I need to use the previous approach with getHibernateTemplate().

Here's the association between my form and the user_id that is failing to populate:

```
<id name="id">
  <generator class="native"/>
</id>
...
...
<many-to-one column="user_id" name="user" not-null="false"/>
```

The SQL statements that are generated in both cases are identical except the fact that the user_id is not being inserted into the parameters properly.

Comment: Weird. Can you show what SQL is performed in both cases. Also, could you add some details about the association between `EcoFormFill` and `User` (is it bidirectional?). As a side note, I don't recommend using the `HibernateTemplate`, but this is another story (see http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/).

Comment: Thanks for your response Pascal,
I just updated my question, please see above.

Comment: Ok. So this is a "fake" many-to-one? Do you also have an association from `User` to `EcoFormFill`? And do you get the same result when using `get()` instead of `load()`?

Comment: I wasn't aware it was a 'fake' one... and I do not have an association from User to EcoFormFill.

I did try both get() and load() with no success

Comment: Well, when I look at your code, it looks like a one-to-one association (you're not adding the user to a collection, are you?), that's why I called it a fake many-to-one. Anyway, this doesn't answer the question and I don't know how to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trevor is your application context seem to be like this

```
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="yourRootPackage" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>                
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

take look above, this part represent the minimum needed in your application context.